# .NET Core / IIS Express / Unable To Start Process 'MySite.exe' 403 Forbidden (Q&A)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a website using Visual Studio. It's using .NET Core 3.1.

Although it works fine on my machine, on someone elses machine, the website wont start in IIS Express. The Error is:

> Unable to start process
>   C:\users\myuser\repo\project\bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1\mysite.exe.
>   The web server request failed with status code 403, Forbidden. The
>   full response has been written to
>   C:\users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\HttpFailure_XX_XX_XX.html

The error in the html file doesn't provide much information.

If he tries creating a blank .NET Core site on his machine, it works.

If we try 'Start without debugging', the site works, but it won't work in debug.

What can we do to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we searched the internet, but couldn't find the exact answer.

The actual answer was:

- Remove the Web.Config file completely from the project and try it. After doing this, we could debug the site.
- Re-add the Web.Config file and, by trial and error, remove things that appear suspicious to find the exact cause.

In our case, the following line was the culprit:

```
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Hope this helps someone.